# How to do join query similar operation in azure datafactory dataflow component

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am using dataflow component to perform the csv file transformation and we implemented source operation and select component to query the data. we would like to implement on top the component to implement similar SQL queryoperation.

[image]

```
select col1,id,col1,col1,col1,col1,
col1,col1,col1,col1,col1
from tableA a
join tableB b
on a.id = b.id
left join tableC c
on a.id = c.id
```

I needs to implement the similar SQL operation in adf data flow.

Comment: Use Join transformation in data flow

Comment: can you plz share me with condition based, ON condition in sql available right, similar we required

Answer (score 0):

- Take the join transformation in dataflow after source transformations.
- Enter the left stream and right stream.
- Enter the join type.
- In join conditions, give the matching conditions.

Refer the below screenshot.

[image]

Reference: [azure-docs/data-flow-join.md at main · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs (github.com)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/data-factory/data-flow-join.md)

Comment: in my case, i have to do first just join A table with B table but in join component showing option is inner join,full outer,left outer,left outer,right outer,custom.. but i wan to do just join A and B and C table needs do left join. i am confussing which option, I could have to use in my against SQL query, please suggest

Comment: 1) Join table1 and table2 using inner join option. 2) Then join the result of join1 with table3 using left join option

Comment: what about left stream and right stream ?

Comment: 1) for 1st inner join ..you can take table1 as left and table2 as right.
2) for 2nd left join, you can take resulting join1 as left and table3 as right.